# NSViewController story board with coded anchors collapses window

Tags: swift, cocoa, autolayout

I'm having trouble mixing story boards and coded autolayout in Cocoa + Swift.  It should be possible right?

I started with a NSTabViewController defined in a story board with default settings as dragged out of the toolbox.  I added an NSTextField view via code.  And I added anchors.  Everything works as expected except the bottom anchor.

After adding the bottom anchor, the window and controller seem to collapse to the size of the NSTextField.  I expected the opposite, that the text field get stretched to fill the height of the window.

What am I doing wrong?  The literal Frame maybe?  Or some option flag that I'm not setting?

```
class NSTabViewController : WSTabViewController {

var summaryView : NSTextField

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    summaryView = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(20,20,200,40))
    summaryView.font = NSFont(name: "Menlo", size: 9)
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addSubview(summaryView)
    summaryView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    summaryView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
    summaryView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
    summaryView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -5).active = true
    summaryView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).active = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent window from collapsing set lower priority for hugging:

```
 summaryView.setContentHuggingPriority(249, forOrientation: .Vertical)
```

But you actually misuse tab view controller. It just manages views in common use... while you are adding text to the tab header area. There is a very good tutorial of how to use it correctly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TS4H3WvIwpY